# Is reordering multiple items in a recyclerview possible?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper, reorderlist

I used the ItemTouchHelper class, which is a RecyclerView extension. When a single item is long-pressed, ItemDecoration is used to reorder it in the list.

However, the necessity is to choose multiple items before proceeding with the reordering. Is anyone aware of the possibilities?